# Stripe Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: stripe-payments

I am unable to charge a Stripe customer. While this question has been asked a dozen times in the past, none of their mistakes match my problem.

I am calling this function in node.js as a firebase function

```
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      
        customer : customerId,
        amount : amount,
        currency : currency
    });
```

Request POST Body

```
{
  "customer": "cus_JL4hVfDnym2SIk",
  "amount": "500",
  "currency": "usd"
}
```

I have confirmed all of the values are correct on the Stripe Dashboard. As well I have the Test Card stored on the customer and it is definetly set to default, which I have confirmed on the dashboard as well. I store the card information at a much different step, unlike the other posts handle this all at once.

I would like to just charge the customer who has a stored card on their account. Everything is on test data, test card, etc. Is this an issue using charges api? Or does the test card not work here for some reason?

Error Response Body

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/missing",
    "message": "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card",
    "param": "card",
    "type": "card_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards added in the Dashboard now use the newer [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) API. The pattern you're using depends on the customer having a `default_source` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-default_source)) using the legacy [Sources](https://stripe.com/docs/sources) API.

You could [attach the test card as a source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach), but instead I'd suggest changing your integration to use [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents).

If you already have the basic test card added on the customer, you need to provide its `id` as the `payment_method`:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  payment_method: 'pm_123', // put your ID here
  confirm: true,
});
```

While this will work for the 4242 test card, the recommended approach is to [follow this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&lang=node&ui=elements) to integrate with Stripe.js and Elements for [client-side confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment) that supports [Strong Customer Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication).

Comment: Great response. Ideally I didn't want to store and pass around my payment_method as this creates a few edge cases in the project. However this might be the only solution as I stored my default_source with "paymenthMethods.attach" and "customers.update". Additionally those tutorials are great, except I had to convert the card element to a SwiftUI View and my stored card and purchase flow are at completely separate junctures. Might mark this correct later as potentially the PaymentMethod and Sources API might have different default_payments objects, which would explain my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note that when using Payment Methods there is no built-in "default" PM for one-time payments. There is a customer `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` for Invoices (and Subscriptions), but for one-time Payment Intents you must always explicitly provide a payment method. If appropriate for your business, you can save a PM id to use as the default, but you will need to provide this parameter to the payment intent.

Comment: Ohh that makes more sense. What I might do is call "paymentMethods.retrieve" to obtain the default stored card for subscriptions, as a shortcut. If that doesn't work then I'll just pass my payment_method through the app as you originally suggested. Thanks for you help!

Comment: The shortcut method worked for me (in case anyone else is wondering)